# Why the subdomains are not working with express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hosts

so I am experimenting with it locally, this is in my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       example.dev
127.0.0.1       www.example.dev
127.0.0.1       api.example.dev
```

and this is my code:

```
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

// example.com 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Homepage');
});

//api specific routes 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        { name: "Brian" }
    ]);
});

app.use(subdomain('api', router));
app.listen(3000);
```

it's basically the example from the package website
api.example.dev/users works well, but when I go to to api.example.dev the content is the same as on example.dev (like it is overwritten)
any ideas what I am doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a order of requests processing problem. Move the declaration of the request handler for the main domain after the subdomain:

```
var subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

//api specific routes 
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        { name: "Brian" }
    ]);
});

app.use(subdomain('api', router));

// example.com 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Homepage');
});

app.listen(3000);
```